# My "Hamburger" won't load my unorded list

Tags: jquery, html, razor, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to incorporate a "Hamburger" style menu to my page when it gets to the "md" size. The hamburger menu appears but when I click on it nothing happens.

I've tried taking out some of the classes from some of the tags but it relies pretty heavily on the bootstrap classes so I can't do that.

When I take out the "sidebar" class from the div with id="mySidebar" the hamburger works to display the UL but the list won't collapse back into hamburger. Also, it destorys the menu when its not in the "md" size, so I don't think that's a good fix.

I have linked my jQuery before my Bootstrap as well.

I want to be able to keep my styling for the page when it is in full size, but when it goes down to MD or smaller, to use the hamburger menu. The hamburger menu should be able to show and hide the entire menu and only be available when the screen is at the smaller size.

-Invosuite

```
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark bg-dark" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar sidebar-grid">
            <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
                <div data-scrollbar="true" data-height="100%" data-init="true" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-header nav-item dropdown">New Pages</li>
                            <!-- Links Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub nav-link">
                                <a asp-page="/LinksPages/DashboardLinks">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Links</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Extrusion Dept Pages-->
                            <li class="has-sub nav-link">
                                <a asp-page="/ExtrusionDept/DashboardLotNumberLog">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Lot Number Log</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Usable Pages</li>
                            <!-- Customer Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub">
                                <a asp-page="/CustomerPages/DashboardCustomer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Customers</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Requisition Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub">
                                <a asp-page="/RequisitionPages/DashboardRequisition">
```

Here are my scripts at the top of my file.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="868070943934-0de347s86s6mpd53uajacok30k5vlud0.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<!-- ================== BEGIN BASE CSS STYLE ================== -->
@*<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<link href="~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/assets/plugins/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- ================== Default Style ================== -->
<link href="~/assets/css/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/assets/css/default/style-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/assets/css/default/theme/default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme" />
<!-- ================== END ================== -->
```

Here are the scripts at the bottom of my page

```
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
<script src="../assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/theme/default.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/apps.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- ================== END BASE JS ================== -->
<!-- ================== BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
<script src="../assets/plugins/highlight/highlight.common.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/demo/render.highlight.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include your jQuery code

Comment: @symlink You want to see the link or the code in the file which i'm linking to?

Comment: The code itself. Whatever is supposed to be toggling the menu. Unless this is a native Bootstrap thing

Comment: @symlink it is a native Bootstrap thing,
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/hamburger-menu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Possibly reexamine the order and version of scripts. I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 followed by Bootstrap 4.3.1:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark bg-dark" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar sidebar-grid">
            <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
                <div data-scrollbar="true" data-height="100%" data-init="true" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 100%;">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-header nav-item dropdown">New Pages</li>
                            <!-- Links Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub nav-link">
                                <a asp-page="/LinksPages/DashboardLinks">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Links</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Extrusion Dept Pages-->
                            <li class="has-sub nav-link">
                                <a asp-page="/ExtrusionDept/DashboardLotNumberLog">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Lot Number Log</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Usable Pages</li>
                            <!-- Customer Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub">
                                <a asp-page="/CustomerPages/DashboardCustomer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                    <span>Customers</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Requisition Pages -->
                            <li class="has-sub">
                                <a asp-page="/RequisitionPages/DashboardRequisition">
```

Comment: I added my scripts/links in my original post, do you think these are conflicting?

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden you have `jquery-ui` but not `jquery`. You also have `boostrap` twice.

Comment: I believe i have jquery at the bottom of my page, i added it to the original post to show you.

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden I see. It still looks like you have duplicates of a few libraries. I would try removing those/commenting those out, first

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden Also, check for any JavaScript errors in your browser inspector console.

Comment: No javascript errors, a jQuery and Bootstrap error which i'm confused by. Also, i'm not seeing the duplicate links that you are talking about..

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden I'm not sure. Are `boostrap.bundle.min` and `bootstrap.min` different libraries? What about `jquery-3.3.1.min` and `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min`? The fact that it works in the small example in my answer and not in your app surely means there are some libraries that are conflicting or not in the right order.

Comment: Thank you, I had a style sheet that was conflicting and I figured out which one it was!